# Joomla User Profile

Tags: joomla

How do I add user profiles to my website which is being maintained using Joomla? I am new to Content Management Systems and I would like to know from scratch. A link to some tutorial would be really helpful.

Comment: In the Joomla backend, go to **Users >> User Manager >> Add New User**

Answer (score 0):

Follow this tutorial, it explains very well how to insert new users to Joomla using the administrator:

http://docs.joomla.org/Adding_a_new_user

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to add a user or how to add new profile fields? TO add profile fields you need to write a profile plugin or add profiles to the existing plugin and then manage who gets which forms.

http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_profile_plugin

Comment: Hi Elin. I meant adding a page where users can register and themselves on my site and create a profile for themselves.I am sorry if I conveyed some other meaning in my question.

Comment: Well Joomla comes with registration built in, just make a menu link to the registration page. That lets them edit their basic user settings. Joomla also comes with an example profile plugin which you can enable and configure. This lets you add extra fields to the registration and profile edit forms and make them optional or required. Many people just change the language strings for the core form and use that, but you can also make your own. This is all discussed in detail at docs.joomla.org.